# Stack too deep, try using less variables on creating contract

Tags: solidity

I am trying to create a contract from a contract factory using the following function:

```
function createContract(string _var1, string _var2,
        uint32 _var3, string _var4, string _var5,
        string _var6, uint32 _var7, uint32 _var8, uint32 _var9,
        uint32 _var10, uint32 _var11)
public returns (address contractAddress) {

    return new Contract(_var1, random1, random2, _var2,
        _var3, _var4, _var5, _var6, _var7, _var8,
        _var9, _var10, _var11);

}
```

N.B. `random1` and `random2` are fields in the contract factory.

This function throws `Stack too deep, try using less variables`. I have read that I should split up the function etc. to get around this, but obviously, that is not an option here. Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: Why can you not use fewer variables?

Comment: The contract represents an entity that requires those variables. Note that the real names of the variables are masked as this is for a client.

Answer (score 0):

So, initially I tried grouping the variables by type into this:

```
function createContract(string[] _var1, uint32[] _var2)
public returns (address contractAddress) {

    return new Contract(_var1, random1, random2, _var2);

}
```

However, nested dynamic arrays are not supported at this time. As `string` is represented as `byte[]` in EVM, a `string[]` is in fact passed as a `byte[][]`.

I ended up grouping the `uint32` and leaving the strings:

```
function createContract(string _var1, string _var2, uint32[] _var3,
        string _var4, string _var5, string _var6)
public returns (address contractAddress) {

    return new Contract(_var1, random1, random2, _var2,
        _var3, _var4, _var5, _var6);

}
```

**EDIT**: Even though this method works, it is badly designed. See my other answer for a better workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

I went one step further with this as having an array of `unit32` is ambiguous and confusing in terms of the position of a specific argument.

My final attempt utilized the `struct` type to provide a less ambiguous implementation. This `struct` is in a `library` in a separate file `Library.sol`:

```
struct ContractArgs {
    uint32 var1;
    string var2;
    uint32 var3;
    ....
}
```

The factory method looks like this:

```
function createContract(Library.ContractArgs _contractArgs)
public returns (address contractAddress) {

    return new Contract(_contractArgs, random1, random2);

}
```

And my constructor looks like this:

```
function Contract(Library.ContructorArgs _contractorArgs, 
        uint32 _supplierId, string _supplierName) {

    contractArgs = _contractArgs;
    random1 = _random1;
    random2 = _random2;

}
```